# iOS App size is outrageous

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store

I have a simple iOS App with 4 Viewcontrollers and few ressources. The Resources include a video (30mb) and images (10mb). I was expecting an app size of max. 50MB but when I archive it goes up to 107MB.

I have read that when I use Swift libraries or pods Xcode includes Swift core into my app. My question is now what should I do? 107MB is unacceptable. Even 50MB is really big but I was fine with. Is there a way to reduce the size and keep the Swift pods included? At this stage I can't even upload it.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @GoRoS I have inspected and found out that libswiftCore.dylib 43MB & libswiftFoundation.dylib 5MB are the files that really increase the size. Still its strange. I have the Swift libraries at two different locations in my IPA.

- IPA

  - iphoneos (contains Swift libs)
  - payload

    - Frameworks (contains obj-c libs and Swift)

Comment: He may want an explanation why his question was so downvoted, don't you think guys?

Comment: Are you using bitcode? That could make the actual deliverable to a device much smaller.

Comment: @thefredelement I do use bitcode. Still 107MB is to big to upload.. Also I'm using Objective-C and Swift pods so I dont think that the size will change at the end.

Comment: @SaifDeen have you got  perfect  answer then please let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SaifDeen, I would recommend to inspect your IPA file by yourself and you will discover why your app is that big ;)

For that just remember that an IPA is a simple ZIP file:

> unzip -lv /path/to/your/app.ipa

Check this [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html)

**Update:**

Disabling bitcode will decrease your IPA size. However, as far as I know, even though you have bitcode enabled once your app is in the store Apple makes some optimizations to the app before the user downloads it. The result of that should be a smaller file size.

Comment: Yeap! It seems that having the bitcode enabled is the cause. Could you try to disable bitcode and see whether you get a different size or not? However, as far as I know, even though you have bitcode enabled once your app is in the store Apple makes some optimizations to the app before the user downloads it. The result of that should be a smaller file size.

Comment: That did it! Now its 80MB still big but I hope Apple dooes some tweaks to iit! ty!

Comment: @SaifDeen happy to hear that ;). Still doesn't understand all your question's downvotes, here you go my +1!

Comment: me2, would like to know who that was. anway, can you add your hint with disabling bitcode to your answer? I think that would help a lot :)

Comment: I used this to sort them into a text file: unzip -lv APPNAME.ipa | sort -k 3 -nr > MYNEWFILE.txt

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue with my app and the only way that I was able to see the final size of the app is not when archiving, is once the app is on Apple servers. The best way to test this is archiving and upload it to iTunes Connect and then installing it with TestFlight.

In my case, at first was around 90 MB and then when installing with TestFlight was only 39 MB.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

bitcode and swift libraries DID NOT have anything to do with my issue.... i basically simply clicked and dragged a folder into my xcode project, which automatically added everything in that folder as 'targets'.

However, these files did not come up when searching through my target dependencies within xcode.... but they DID INDEED show up when unzipping the .ipa as @GoRoS had suggested previously in this thread.

This was a dumb mistake that i probably should have caught sooner.... but that also means someone else will make the same mistake too : )

screen shots...

**i clicked and dragged this folder (ios_alpha) from finder into xcode...**
[image]

**and then everything inside that folder was set as a target membership like this....**

[image]

hope this helps someone!
glhf!