# Flutter IOS app size 4x higher than Android

Tags: ios, flutter

My flutter app is around 20Mo on Android, and around 80Mo on IOS.

What to do more to reduce IOS app size ?

- run flutter clean ;
- run pod cache clean --all;
- compress image files ;
- remove unnecessary packages ;

Then when I run "flutter build ios --analyze-size" total size is 86Mb with:

- runner 5Mb
- grpcpp.framework 2Mb
- libswiftCore.dylib 6Mb
- Flutter.framework 10Mb
- RevenueCat.framework 5Mb
- App.framework 18Mo
- Dart AOT symbols accounted decompressed size 13Mb
- package:flutter 4Mb
- package: myApp-xxxx 2Mb
- FirebaseFirestoreInternal.framework 5Mb
- grpc.framework 7mb
- openssl_grpc.framework 2Mb
- libswiftFoundation.dylib 3Mb

Answer (score 0):

I would consider looking through this thread: [iOS App size is outrageous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325460/ios-app-size-is-outrageous?rq=2)

Statistically speaking IOS apps are much larger than Android apps, Facebook is a good example with it being almost 0.5GB on IOS and 72MB on Android. (https://www.dignited.com/35243/why-are-ios-apps-bigger-than-equivalent-android-apps/)

I would argue your file sizes fall within the realm of accuracy for IOS to Android ratios.

Apologies this doesn't state ways to reduce your file size etc, however I feel this is a key factor for your file size differential.

Comment: This thread is old (2016), there is no improvement since 7 years... ??

Comment: Not from what I've been able to find, I'm pretty sure its down to how IOS is designed!

https://mobilityarena.com/ios-apps-are-larger-than-android-apps/

This article from 2020 states the similar 4X app size theme. Supposedly from what I can find this appears to be the norm.